# Using the INSIDE function in C

Tags: c, arrays, char

Small query: in Python, I know that you can check if char `a` is inside array `b` by saying:

```
 b = ['a', 'b', 'c', ...] # would be filled with letters
 if str(a) in b:
      # instructions.
```

Is there a similar operator or method for this in language C?

Comment: Is `a` a character or a string?

Comment: In case you are just asking it for an array of chars (null terminated) you can check `strchr` function. If you are asking something more general you will need to implement it according to the array element type.

Comment: @gspr a is a single character

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the needle is a single `char`, then you can use either `strchr` or `memchr`. `strchr` only works if the haystack is null terminated, but you don't need to know the length in advance. `memchr` works even without a null terminator, but you do need to tell it the length. Examples of each:

```
#include <string.h>

char b1[] = { 'a', 'b', 'c' /* ... */, '\0' };
if(strchr(b1, a)) /* ... */;

char b2[] = { 'a', 'b', 'c' /* ... */ };
if(memchr(b2, a, sizeof b2)) /* ... */;
```

If the needle is an array of `char`s, then you can use `strstr` or `memmem`, with analogous differences. Examples of each:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <string.h>

char b1[] = { 'a', 'b', 'c' /* ... */, '\0' };
if(strstr(b1, a)) /* ... */;

char b2[] = { 'a', 'b', 'c' /* ... */ };
if(memmem(b2, sizeof b2, a, sizeof a)) /* ... */;
```

Comment: Thanks! the         strchr        Seems best suited for this.